# attiny85 and arduino - analogRead + pwmOut

Tags: programming, pwm

I am using the Arduino IDE to program the attiny85. I want to take an incoming analog reading, then based on that reading, output a specific PWM value. Here's my circuit:

[image: my circuit]

and here's my code:

```
// to run on attiny85

const byte pwmPin = 0;
const byte analogInPin = A2;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pwmPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int analogIn = analogRead(analogInPin);
  analogWrite(pwmPin, analogIn);
}
```

should be very simple- I have no problems uploading code to the attiny85, and no problems with simple tests like outputting a specific PWM value (not based on the analog read). but when I try to combine the two- read, then write that value, I can't seem to get things to work. In this circuit for example- I get a reading of 1023 (5v) on the arduino micro- instead of a reading of ~ 790 (3.85v) which is what I should expect. I've used a multimeter to verify the voltages in this circuit- so I think I must either be doing something wrong with my expectations of how to wire up or program the attiny85.

Comment: A schematic of your circuit would probably be more helpful than an implementation schema with a breadboard. Do you have such a schematic? If yes, add it to your question.

Comment: I don't see any clock (quartz or ceramic resonator) for your ATtiny, is this normal?

Comment: @jfpoilpret yeah you have a few choices for using the internal clock.

Comment: Did you try to add a short delay in your loop? What may happen is that your loop is running too fast, and each new `analogWrite()` call would "reset" the PWM of the pin, making it always up (no time to use PWM). I would try `delay(1000)` for a start.

Comment: Did your multimeter read 3.85v after the low pass filter? (so right on the Micro's input pin)

Comment: i needed to re-range the input to 8 bit. `analogIn = map(analogIn, 0, 1023, 0, 255);`

Comment: it works fine. btw i am using the internal 8mhz - attiny85. also using arduino-tiny core. thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: just to clarify - the adc input on the attiny85 is 10bit. the pwm output is 8bit. thus the map().

Comment: @GradeSchool It would be helpful if you could write your solution as an actual answer, so that future visitors can find it more easily. Thanks!

Comment: i tried to do that, but this site won't let me for like 8 more hours. i will do so as soon as i can.

Comment: Could you throw in some capitals in your text to improve readability? Also a proper circuit diagram, rather than a wiring diagram would help a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Analog read is 10-bits (2^10 = 0-1023 range), analog write is 8-bits (2^8 = 0-255 range). Ditch the lower two bits of the result either by doing:

```
analogIn = analogIn >> 2;
```

which can be shortened to:

```
analogIn >>= 2;
```

Or you can use the rather complex map function:

```
analogIn = map( analogIn(0, 1023, 0, 255) )
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the answer in the comments.

Comment: +1 Not a problem. It's good to have it all spelled out in a proper answer anyway.

Answer (score 4):

i needed to re-range the 10bit input to 8 bit for the pwm out.

```
// to run on attiny85

const byte pwmPin = 0;
const byte analogInPin = A2;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  pinMode(pwmPin, OUTPUT);
  int analogIn = analogRead(analogInPin);
 analogIn = map(analogIn, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
 analogWrite(pwmPin, analogIn);
}
```

Comment: the `map` function takes a *lot* of clock cycles compared to the bitshift describes in Cybergibbons' answer.